# Django reversion - Get old model with old model children (get historical object)

Tags: django, django-reversion

I'm trying to get an old version of an object and then also get the old children belonging to that model. I'll try to add an example here:

```
parent_object.teams.count()
# => 10
```

And then after fetching the old model with something like `versions[1]`

```
old_parent_object.teams.count()
# => 8
```

Is this even possible?

The example above is much simplified. In reality i need to get the old parent object with nested children as they where when the old parent object existed. So not just the count, but the whole object.